# Is there an intrinsic timezone for a date column in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails.  When you save a column with type `datetime` then an intrinsic timezone is stored for the date and time.  How is a column of type `date` stored and in particular is there any timezone associated with the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Garrett Motzner's comments, there is no intrinsic timezone stored with `date` column as opposed to a `datetime` column which does have a timezone associated with it. This means that if users have different timezones, then  you will need to manually account for the timezone if using a `date` column. The alternative is to use a `datetime` column to store the date and process it to account for the fact that only a date is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Active record tries to retrieve all stored dates as UTC, although you can configure it to use a local time:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

> `config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use `Time.local` (if set to `:local`) or `Time.utc` (if set to `:utc`) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is `:utc.`

Comment: I have a model ```Game``` with a field ```compdate```  which is of  type ```date``` and a field ```created_at``` with type ```datetime```. If I load an instance from the database i.e. ```game=Game.first``` and then examine these two fields I get ```Tue, 23 May 2017 08:41:32 UTC +00:00``` for the ```created_at``` field which explicitly shows the timezone. If I examine the ```compdate``` field I get ```Wed, 11 Jun 2014``` which does not show the timezone. So if date fields have a timezone how is it stored?

Comment: Ah, missed the part about _date_ and not _datetime_. Well, Dates don't really have timezones. if you need a timezone, then you really want a `datetime`.  What exactly is it that you want to record in `compdate`? Do you need the beginning of the day in a particular timezone, or the end of the day, or both, or something else?

Comment: From an api I am receiving a date and the timezone relevant to that date. I am storing both the timezone and the date. I want to make sure that there is no intrinsic timezone being stored with the date which can later conflict with the known timezone. Is the date just stored as a string of form '2018-07-03'?

Comment: Yes, as I said, ruby and rails don't have dates with timezones, although they do have times with zones. So there is no default way for a date to have a zone. So if rails loads a `Date` object from the database, it can't have a zone. But be careful when working with dates, because they are subtly different than times, and I have from experience ran across a whole bunch of edge cases when trying to translate them to times. It is often easier to work with times instead of dates, especially if you need a zone.